# Extract substring in BASH script whit characters treated as numbers

Tags: string, bash, grep, substring, character

I need to extract a substring of string in bash script.
This is the code with "echos":

```
echo "number:"
echo "$number"
echo "bb"
registers3=$(echo $number | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')
registers2="$(grep -oE '[0-9]+' <<< "$number")"
registers="${number//[^0-9]/}"
valor=$(grep -o "[0-9]" <<<"$number")
echo "valor:"
echo $valor
echo "reg:"
echo "$registers"
echo "reg2:"
echo "$registers2"
echo "reg3:"
echo "$registers3"
```

And this the output:

```
   number:
/ >  -------
420
/ >
bb
valor:
1 0 3 4 4 2 0
reg:
1034420
reg2:
1034
420
reg3:
1034
420
```

the problem is the special characters of $number.

can you help me to extract only the number. in this case is "421"

Thanks!!!

EDIT:
If i put $number in file ($number> file.txt) and open with vi and :set list i get:

```
^[[?1034h/ >  -------$
420$
/ > $
```

Comment: Your example is confusing, particularly because you're not using quotes around your variables (e.g. `echo "$number"`) so the output is mangled. To be honest, it looks as though the main problem is that you're doing `echo $number | grep` instead of `echo "$number" | grep`.

Comment: Thanks Tom fot the help. i edit mi post with the quotes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
registers=$(echo $number | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')
```

try this:

```
registers="$(grep -oE '[0-9]+' <<< "$number")"
```

or even better, this one:

```
registers="${number//[^0-9]/}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! but not work.  with the first option i get this output:reg: 1034 420 and with the second this: 1034420

Comment: What was the exact value of `$number` when you run the above lines?

Comment: The value of number i edit in mi post. it's number:
/ >  -------
420
/ > (with \n)

Comment: Try this: Do `number=$'/ > ------- 420 / >\n'`, then try one my 2 solutions, e.g. `registers="${number//[^0-9]/}"` and then do `echo "$registers"`.

Comment: in this case they WORK! but the problem is (i think) is that the in original $number i have \n (or another special character) (see the output of the original post i have 3 \n). Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: Line breaks (`\n`) shouldn't matter. The example I gave you in my previous comment included a line break.

Comment: Yes! the problem maybe is the return character with 1034 (see edit post)